# Angular2 with Typescript - Error loading angular2/platform/browser

Tags: angular

I have spent way too much time on this, but I am stuck and can't figure out how to get Angular2 with Typescript to run.  I keep getting a 404 for the components:

Error loading http://localhost:5000/angular2/platform/browser as "angular2/platform/browser" from http://localhost:5000/appScripts/boot.js

[image]

Here is my folder structure:[image]

My index.html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Angular 2 with ASP.NET Core</title>
<!-- 1. Load libraries -->
<script src="libs/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="libs/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="libs/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>


<!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
<script src="./appScripts/config.js"></script>
<script>

    System.import('appScripts/boot')
          .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>

</head>
<body>
<my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

The boot.ts:

```
 /// <reference path="../node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts" />
    import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser'
    import {AppComponent} from './app'
    bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

The app.ts:

```
    /// <reference path="../typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />
    /// <reference path="../typings/angularjs/angular-route.d.ts" />
    /// <reference path="../typings/angularjs/angular.d.ts" />

    import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
    @Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: 'My First Angular 2 App'
    })
    export class AppComponent { }
```

The config.js

```
(function (global) {

    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    var map = {
        'app': 'appScripts', // 'dist',
        'rxjs': 'libs/rxjs',
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'libs/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
        '@angular': 'libs/@angular'
    };

    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    var packages = {
        'app': { main: 'boot.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    };

    var packageNames = [
      '@angular/common',
      '@angular/compiler',
      '@angular/core',
      '@angular/http',
      '@angular/platform-browser',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
      '@angular/router',
      '@angular/router-deprecated',
      '@angular/testing',
      '@angular/upgrade',
    ];

    // add package entries for angular packages in the form '@angular/common': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
    packageNames.forEach(function (pkgName) {
        packages[pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
    });

    var config = {
        map: map,
        packages: packages
    }

    // filterSystemConfig - index.html's chance to modify config before we register it.
    if (global.filterSystemConfig) { global.filterSystemConfig(config); }

    System.config(config);

})(this);
```

Here is more of the folder structure to give you a better idea of the project structure.
[image]

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "ASP.NET",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "~3.1.0",
    "gulp-concat": "~2.6.0",
    "gulp-imagemin": "~2.4.0",
    "imagemin-pngquant": "~4.2.0",
    "jshint": "2.9.2",
    "gulp-jshint": "2.0.0",
    "jshint-stylish": "~2.1.0",
    "rimraf": "~2.5.1",
    "gulp-minify-css": "~1.2.4",
    "gulp-sass": "2.2.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "~1.5.1",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "~1.6.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "1.1.0",
    "gulp-notify": "2.2.0",
    "beepbeep": "1.2.0",
    "gulp-rename": "1.2.2",
    "gulp-sourcemap": "1.0.1",
    "gulp-clean-css": "2.0.6",
    "main-bower-files": "2.13.0",
    "gulp-filter": "4.0.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "gulp-typescript": "^2.13.1",
    "live-server": "1.0.0",
    "typings": "^1.0.4",
    "gulp-tsc": "^1.1.5"
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help and please let me know if I can provide some more details.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're using rc.1 version of angular but trying to import beta version.

You need to use `@angular/..` like this:

```
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { Component } from '@angular/core'; // instead of 'angular2/core'
....
```

For more details see also changelog https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-rc0-2016-05-02

> To import various symbols please adjust the paths in the following
>   way:

```
angular2/core -> @angular/core
angular2/compiler -> @angular/compiler
angular2/common -> @angular/common
angular2/platform/browser -> @angular/platform-browser + @angular/platform-browser-dynamic
angular2/platform/server -> @angular/platform-server
angular2/testing -> @angular/core/testing
angular2/upgrade -> @angular/upgrade
angular2/http -> @angular/http
angular2/router -> @angular/router-deprecated (from beta.17 for backwards compatibility)
new package: @angular/router - component router with several breaking changes
```

Comment: Thanks Yurzui....   You mean within boot.ts, I should change this line  `import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser'` to this `import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic'`

Comment: @Matt Knight Yes exactly

Comment: I may be conflating RC1 with beta.  I hadn't thought of that.   However, that change alone doesn't quite do it.  I still get:  **http://localhost:6722/angular2/core Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
zone.js:323 Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:6722/angular2/core(…)**      Thank you again for your help.

Comment: You have to change all places with `angular2` to `@angular` Follow the link https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html I.e. `import { Component } from '@angular/core';`

Comment: Sorry to be so dense, but are you saying every single reference to angular2 should now be @angular?  I don't see any obvious candidates for this.

Comment: In my answer i've posted the link where is described changes.

Comment: I found the other in app.ts.  Thank you for your help.  import { Component } from '@angular/core';